# Need dynamic decimal places in SQL display

Tags: sql

In a display column I'm getting values as follows:

```
12.000000
12.350000
13.230000
14.560000
```

I need to represent these values with dynamic decimal places upto 2  places i.e if there are zero's then it should ignore. 
for example: 12.35 only , if its 12.500000 then it should display 12.5 only

Comment: What do you need display for "12.0000" - just `12` or `12.` or `12.0`?

Comment: Use `to_char()` to format the number

Answer (score 0):

`float` type removes trailing zeros, at least for SQL Server. Try casting your `decimal` to `float`.

```
SELECT CAST(12.350000 as float)
```

Returns

> 12,35

Comment: thanks kars and david! it worked.. one more thing if i want this current format .. what should I add ? example: 1,235

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following (ANSI standard SQL):

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM TRIM(CAST(CAST(myvalue AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS CHAR(30))))
  FROM mytable;
```

I'm not sure what flavor of SQL you're using but the above should work (the extra `TRIM()` is on the off-chance that the result of the `CAST()` is padded with spaces.